# Adding an input tag only when it is not present in a div id block

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Information:**  I am trying to build a multiple To-Do List app. On clicking the create button a wrapper class with a dynamic id is created in the side panel which consist of class=item (user i/p) and delete icon (fa.fa.trash). Also there is a div block with class=todolistblock created in the middlepanel for every item created in the side panel. The parent of this todolistblock is a wrappertodo class and also has a dynamic id(wraptd).

**Expected Output:** On clicking on the item class I get a blue background in the middlepanel with a input field (dynamicinput) to create the To-Do List.

**Current Output:** I only want append the input tag when it is not present in the current clicked item but unfortunately the current code doesn't work and it keeps appending the (dynamicinput) everytime when clicked on the current item.

What is wrong with my if statement which should not allow appending multiple input tags? I searched a lot on Stackoverflow but no solution worked for me.

```js
var maxvalue=9; //to restrict the number of list items created
var count = 0; //to count the number of list items created
var listitem = '<div class="item">'; //every item i/p by user is in class item
var deleteicon = '<div class="fa fa-trash">'; //delete icon
var dynamicinput = "<input type='text' name='todoinputname' class='todoinput' placeholder='Enter To-Do..'/>";
var i = 1; //to give a unique id to each wrapper div
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#createlistbutton').click(function(){
    var container = '<div class="wrapper" id="'+i+'">'; //each wrapper div has a different id
    var containerTodo = '<div class="wrappertodo" id="wraptd'+i+'">'; //wrapper for todolistblock has dynamic id
    var todolistblock = '<div class="todolistblock" id="todo'+i+'">'; //each todoblock has a dynamic id
    i++; //increment the counter
   var toAdd = $('input[name=newlistitem]').val(); //i/p from user
    if(count<maxvalue) {
     $('.categories').append(container + listitem +toAdd + '</div>' + deleteicon + '</div>' +'</div>');//dynamic adding item
        $('.middlepanel').append(containerTodo + todolistblock + '</div>' + '</div>');//adding a div block in middlepanel
        count +=1;
    } else {
      alert("Not more than 9 list can be created");
    } 
  });  
  
  
  $('.categories').on('click','.item',function(){
    var thisId = $(this).parent().attr('id'); //obtaining the id of wrapper class container
    $('.item').removeClass('item-bg-color'); //remove existing class for blue bg effect
    $('.wrappertodo').hide(); // hide all todolistblocks initially
    $(this).addClass('item-bg-color'); //add blue bg only for corresponding clicked item
    $('#wraptd'+thisId).addClass('active');//add blue bg only for correspnding todolistblock
    $('#wraptd'+thisId).fadeIn('slow');
    if(!$('#todo'+thisId).hasClass('todoinput')) //to check if current todolistblock already has dynamicinput field
     {
        $('#todo'+thisId).append(dynamicinput); //if not present append the input field(dynamicinput)
     }
    
  });
 
  
    $('main').on('click',".fa.fa-trash", function(){
    var thisId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('#'+thisId).remove();
    $('#wraptd'+thisId).remove();
    count -= 1;   
  });

});
```

```css
*{  margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  font-family: "Times New Roman","Open Sans",sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
 /**background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f06, yellow);**/ 
  background-color: #b9d2d4;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/45-degree-fabric-dark.png");
  width:100%;
}

h3{
  color:#f0f8ff;
  margin: 18 0 0 10;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-bar{
  height: 10%;
  background-color:#303030;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
  margin-right:15;
  padding:0;
  float:right;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li{
  float:left;
  margin-top:5;
  
}

li a{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:None;
  padding: 8px;
  color:#f0f8ff;
   padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align:center;
}

li a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-weight:bold;
}

footer p{
   margin-top:25px;
   }

footer{
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:10%;
   width:100%;
   color:#f0f8ff;
   background:#303030;}
   

   
.sidepanel{
   width:25%;
   float:left;
   text-align:center;
   height:80%;
   background-color:white;
  }

.createinputlist{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
   
}

#createlistbutton{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#303030;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
 }

input[type=text]{
  width:60%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.wrapper{
  text-align:center;
  
}

.wrappertodo{
  text-align:center;
  position:absolute;
  height:80%;
  width:50%;
}

.item{
  border: 1px solid #303030;
  background-color:#f0f8ff;
  border-radius:10px;
  margin-bottom:1em;
  display:inline-block;
  width:90%;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.item:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

.item-bg-color{
  background-color:lightskyBlue;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.fa.fa-trash{
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.categories{
  max-height:80%;
  position:inherit;
}

.chatpanel{
   width:25%;
   float:right;
   text-align:center;
   height:80%;
   background-color:white;
  }

#tempmsg{
  margin-top:70%;
  
}
  
.middlepanel{
  display:inline-block;
  height:80%;
  width:50%;
}

.todolistblock{

}

.active{
  background-color:lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Python Flask App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="src-animation.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

  <body>
  <header>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <h3>PYTHON FLASK APP</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </header>
  
    <main>
  <div class="sidepanel">
    <div class="createinputlist">
    <input type="text" name="newlistitem" placeholder="Enter a List Name"/>
       <button id="createlistbutton">Create List</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="categories">
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="middlepanel">
  </div>
    
  <div class="chatpanel">
    <p id="tempmsg">Chat Panel<br/>Coming soon</p>
  </div>
  </main>
    
  <footer>
    <p>COPYRIGHT &copy 2017 PowerSoft</p>
  </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change item click function

```
$('.categories').on('click','.item',function(){
      //your code
   if(!$('#todo'+thisId).children().hasClass('todoinput')){
      //your code
   }
}
```